# Comparar dos arrays y guardar en un nuevo array los valores mayores

Tags: javascript, funciones, bucle-for

Necesito comparar dos arrays elemento por elemento e imprimir en un nuevo array los elementos mayores de cada uno.
Ejemplo (10>1) agregar 10 al nuevo array, (20>2) agregar 20 al nuevo array.

```
function compareTriplets(a,b) {
 
   let array=[]; 
    for (let i=0; i<a.length; i++){   
        for (let j=0; j<b.length;j++){
            if(a[i]>b[j]){
                array.push(a[i]);
           }
          
            }              
        }
        return array;  
    }
   
    console.log(compareTriplets([10,20,30,40],[1,2,3,4]));
```

Comment: Hola Reyes  estas enviando los "arrays compareTriplets([10,20,30,40],[1,2,3,4]" pero cual seria el resultado que esperas??

Comment: el resultado que deseo obtener es: comparar [10>1] ,[20>2],[20>2],[30>3],[40>4].
en cada una de estas comparaciones me agregue a un nuevo array los números mayores.
Es decir imprimir un array con los datos mayores [10,20,30,40]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{ 
   if(a[i] > b[i])
   {
      c.push(a[i]);
   }
   else
   {
      c.push(b[i]);
   }
}
```

Recorres ambos arreglos con un **ciclo for** y vas preguntando cual elemento es mayor, y en dependencia de cual sea mayor ese es el que insertas en el arreglo nuevo.